# Bevel modifier not working on round boolean cut

Tags: bevel, boolean-modifier

How can I have the bevel modifier applied to the object in front? The object in back shows the working bevel modifier.

[image]

[image]

Edit: Add deleting edge screencast

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Answer (score 0):

You can see there is two edges very close to each other, which "blocks" the bevel modifier. After you remove the edge, the modifier will display porperly
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Alas that doesn't seem to work